# Page Total in case of Multipage print pdf Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to print page total at page footer if we have contents in table (i.e. Amount total per page wise in case of multipage where table expanded to another page) ??

Comment: Please add some code. I don't fully understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: For example you have one table in pdf  (tablefromTextArray), and this table expands more than one page. Like table content 1,2,3 in single page and 4,5,6 in next page. Now what we want is that the amount total of content 1,2,3 should be in page footer of first page.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, Do you have any code or do you want to write this from scratch.

Comment: have code but its lengthy to write entire code here...